# Dictionary value as result of other key's values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I want to assign a value to a given key which is the result of operating on some other keys...

```
a = { 'cpu': {'max':100,'scale':10,'div':a['cpu']['max'] / a['cpu']['scale']} }
```

So, as per the above example, my expected output would have been...

```
a = { 'cpu': {'max':100,'scale':10,'div':10} }
```

... but instead I'm getting `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` which is understandable.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: simply use 100/10 ?

Comment: Add the key in a seperate line? so `a` is already known?

Comment: Hi! Of course, `100/10`, works! But I wanted to only parametrize `max` and `scale`, and getting `div` as an operation between the first two. Adding a second line also works, but I was interested in a one-line solution ...

Comment: not going to happen - it is not yet know to python. `a = (1, a[0])` or `a = [1,a]` won't work for the same reasons

Comment: I thought that some kind of recursion would be of help... but just thinking on it; don't really know how to do it ... thanks any way ...

Comment: I think either way you'll have to define `a` first as @PatrickArtner mentions and then reference it. `a = { 'cpu': {'max':100,'scale': 10 } }; a['div'] = a['cpu']['max'] / a['cpu']['scale']`. Do you have many of such updates? Then a solution using `reduce` may make sense.